# I want to compare 2 timestamps and see if the dates are greater than 2 weeks apart

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 timestamps and see if the dates are greater than 2 weeks apart

**Here are my 2 example timestamps:**

1465337606 and 1470506113

How would I compare them to see if the days are greater than 2 weeks e.g. 14 days

Answer (score 0):

you can convert them to yyyy-mm-dd format using

```
 var currentDate  = new Date(1470506113);
 var secondDate = new Data(1465337606);
```

and then, you can just build the current yyyy-mm-dd from date object and do a regular string comparison:

```
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
var dis = Math.abs(currentDate.getDate() - secondDate.getDate());

id(dis > 14){
     document.write("distance is" + dis + " days") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract timestamps, convert to days and compare:

```
Math.abs(1465337606 - 1470506113) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 > 14; // false
// it is not greater than 14 days
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. I did this: 1470507130 and  this 1459538537
The answer i got was this:  0.12695130787037037

Comment: @AngularM it means that the dates are 0.12695130787037037 days apart

Comment: So would that be 13 days rounded?

Comment: @AngularM 0.1269 day is around 3 minutes

Answer (score -1):

In order to answer the question, first you need to know what sort of timestamps your question is using. JavaScript timestamps are the number of MILLIseconds since January 1, 1970.  Either your timestamps are NOT JavaScript timestamps, or they are for dates within the first month of January 1970.

Your timestamps look like they might be PHP or MySQL timestamps, which are based on the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

Once you understand the unit of time that your timestamps are based on (e.g., seconds or milliseconds), all you need to do is subtract one timestamp from the other, and see if the difference is greater than the number of seconds (or milliseconds) in two weeks. (Which I'll assume you know how to calculate).

If the direction of the difference is important, pay attention to which timestamp you use as the minuend and which is the subtrahend, and note the sign of the difference. If you only need to know the amount of time between the timestamps, and the direction doesn't matter, you can use apply the JavaScript "Math.abs" method to the difference to always return a positive number.